# Which Internet Explorer versions does HTML5 BOILERPLATE support?

Tags: html, html5boilerplate

Can someone please elaborate on which versions of Internet Expolorer the HTML5 ★ BOILERPLATE framework supports?

Does it have support for IE versions 7 & 8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current version supports IE8+. From https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate#features:

> - Cross-browser compatible (Chrome, Firefox, IE8+, Opera, Safari).

Boilderplate v4 supports IE6+, but is no longer maintained:

> [HTML5 Boilerplate v4 provides legacy browser support](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/tree/v4) (IE 6+, Firefox 3.6+, Safari 4+), but is no longer actively developed.

Comment: The current version now only supports IE8+, the legacy V4 version maintains IE6+ support but isn't "actively developed".

Answer (score 1):

HTML 5 doesn't work in most versions of IE. So HTML5 boilerplate uses Modenizer and X-UA-Compatible to make most of it work. You can read about all of it on their github profile.

### **SEE DOCS:**

- https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/v4.2.0/doc/html.md
- https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/v4.2.0/doc/html.md#modernizr
- https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/v4.2.0/doc/html.md#x-ua-compatible